# How to get dom attributes with signed integers values in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, dom

I need to use signed integers as attributes values like this :

```
<li class="doc ui-state-default" value="-6805472">
```

When I tried to retrieve this value in jQuery using `$(li).attr('value')`
it returns `0` instead of the real value. Could you please help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `li`? Provide minimalistic sample to replicate issue

Comment: `li` doesn't have a `value` attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you should wrap the `li` selector in quotes as it's a string. Also, `value` is not a valid attribute on the `li` element. More importantly however is that adding your own custom attributes will render the page invalid and may cause UI and JS issues.

Instead, use `data-*` attributes, as they were intended for this purpose:

```
<li class="doc ui-state-default" data-value="-6805472">
```

You can then access this value using jQuery's `data()` method:

```
var foo = $('li').data('value'); // = -6805472
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oxbgmb7n/)

Comment: Good point regarding `data-*` attributes but doesn't explain why OP's code doesn't work on IE (returns 0), or i miss something?!

Comment: @A.Wolff That's true, and honestly I don't know why IE returns 0 - as it really shouldn't be. All I can offer at this point is guidance on best practices and a working solution.